# Status and Documentation on Aptana 3?

Tags: html, ide, aptana

Recently I downloaded Aptana Studio 3 because it's widely recommended.   When I first ran it, it put up a dialog saying it was *"configuring git support"* with no button to opt out of this.  When I let it proceed it put up a "progress dialog" saying *“Configuring Git support (could take a few minutes)”* with a grayed-out cancel button and it wouldn’t let me minimize the (full-screen) Aptana window so I had no access to my desktop to do other work while waiting.  After 10 minutes I killed Aptana in Task Mgr.

I restarted Aptana and in the Start Page I clicked on Aptana Documentation **but it sent me to a page about Titanium!**   Questions:

- What is Titanium and does it replace Aptana?  (i.e., should I be
  using it instead?)
- Where is the Aptana documentation?
- Is Aptana still being maintained, i.e., should I report my
  experiences to them as bugs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Titanium is a product that is built on top of Aptana Studio plugins. As you may know, Aptana was acquired by Appcelerator at the beginning of 2011. Titanium Studio is the main tool for Web and Titanium developers. Appcelerator provides both Aptana Studio and Titanium Studio,  which are in sync in terms of the Aptana Studio features.
2. The documentation is at http://aptana.com/r/apdocs. It includes both Aptana Studio and Titanium Studio docs.
3. Definitively YES. Please report this issue to http://aptana.com/r/apbugs

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator's Titanium offers the same HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby,
Ruby on Rails support as Aptana plus support for Titanium Desktop and Titanium Mobile.

For web development, the following page must be what you're looking for (since
for web development aptana is the same as titanium):

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Web_Development

Regards,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it worked for me when I ran Aptana as an administrator. You can also opt out of configuring git by clicking the red X in the top right corner of the dialog.